# MYSQL trigger issue 33999

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-into

I am trying to create a live update in a history table. Whenever record is inserted/updated in o_training approval table , a corresponding record should be INSERTED in o_training_appr_history table. For this i created below triggers.

1. appr_after_insert

```
**DELIMITER $$
create trigger olattest.appr_after_insert after insert on o_training_approval
for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO o_training_appr_history
select
NEW.request_id,
NEW.user_id,
m.band,
m.grade,
NEW.approver_id,
NEW.approver_role,
NEW.project_id,
NEW.course_id,
NEW.comments,
NEW.submitted_date,
NEW.status_id,
m.vertical,
m.sub_vertical,
m.city,
m.location_type as location
from o_training_approval t join o_master_employees m
on(t.user_id = m.emp_id)
where m.emp_id=NEW.user_id;
END;
$$**
```

1. appr_after_update

```
**DELIMITER $$
create trigger olattest.appr_after_update after update on o_training_approval
for each row
BEGIN
INSERT INTO o_training_appr_history
select
NEW.request_id,
NEW.user_id,
m.band,
m.grade,
NEW.approver_id,
NEW.approver_role,
NEW.project_id,
NEW.course_id,
NEW.comments,
NEW.submitted_date,
NEW.status_id,
m.vertical,
m.sub_vertical,
m.city,
m.location_type as location
from o_training_approval t join o_master_employees m
on(t.user_id = m.emp_id)
where m.emp_id=NEW.user_id;
END;
$$**
```

Both the triggers got created without any error. However, on insert/update on the base table , no record is getting inserted in the history table.

I am clueless as for the reason and solution. Could anyone please help in this regard?

Comment: May be the `where` failed or `join` not matched.

Comment: Further to the comment by @Ravinder, try and run the `INSERT INTO` using the same `NEW.*` values as would appear in your trigger, and confirm that gets results.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. But there is a new development that i need to update. Myself and team are using MYSQL Query browser 1.1.20

Comment: The trigger is working fine froma couple of machines but not working when data inserted from other machines or front end. I dont believe the problem is with the trigger itself.